# Bootstrap form input does not allow for editing when clicked

Tags: css, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

Problem:
My bootstrap form does not allow for editing.

Details:
I am using a bootstrap form within a .thumbnail and the .caption class. I wanted very specific column sizing for each form-group which is why I used a nested grid system. When I click on an input absolutely nothing happens (literally nothing). However, when I connect a jQuery event listener to the input the event does indeed fire. Why does my form appear to be incapable of editing? Thank you in advance!

```html
<div class="thumbnail">
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-centered">
    <h3 id="application-type">Web Development Application</h3>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="caption row">
    <form class="col-xs-12" method="post">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="first-name" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"><strong>First Name</strong></label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input id="first-name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="John">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="last-name" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"><strong>Last Name</strong></label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input id="last-name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Doe" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="apply-email" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"><strong>Email Address</strong></label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input id="apply-email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="johnnyappleseed@gmail.com" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="linked-in" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"><strong>LinkedIn</strong></label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input id="linked-in" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="mylinkedIn.com" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="show-portfolio" style="display: none;" class="form-group row">
        <label for="portfolio" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"><strong>Portfolio</strong></label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input id="portfolio" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="mylinkedIn.com" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="apply-file-btn" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"><strong>CV</strong></label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <ul class="file-btn-group">
            <li>
              <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                                Upload <input class="form-control" type="file">
                            </span>
            </li>
            <li class="file-name">
              <span>No file chosen...</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <button type="submit" class="submit-btn col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-8 btn btn-success btn-mini">Submit!</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: works fine for me.. check here https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/goh8rpcm/2/

Comment: @connor any update?

Comment: Still not working for me, it works in the fiddle but not on my actual page. I've tried removing the form and placing it somewhere else on my page for testing and still nothing. Are you have the same problem @TheDarkNight

Comment: Latest update: If I add required parameter to an input field and then click submit it bring the required field into focus and lets me type.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="thumbnail">
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-centered">
    <h3 id="application-type">Web Development Application</h3>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="caption row">
    <form class="col-xs-12" method="post">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="first-name" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"><strong>First Name</strong></label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input id="first-name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="John">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="last-name" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"><strong>Last Name</strong></label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input id="last-name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Doe" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="apply-email" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"><strong>Email Address</strong></label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input id="apply-email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="johnnyappleseed@gmail.com" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="linked-in" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"><strong>LinkedIn</strong></label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input id="linked-in" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="mylinkedIn.com" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="show-portfolio" style="display: none;" class="form-group row">
        <label for="portfolio" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"><strong>Portfolio</strong></label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input id="portfolio" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="mylinkedIn.com" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="apply-file-btn" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"><strong>CV</strong></label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <ul class="file-btn-group">
            <li>
              <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                                Upload <input class="form-control" type="file">
                            </span>
            </li>
            <li class="file-name">
              <span>No file chosen...</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <button type="submit" class="submit-btn col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-8 btn btn-success btn-mini">Submit!</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your code seems to be working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out a workaround. It isn't the best solution because it requires some jQuery/js and there has to be a way around the problem with the html structure. However, if someone else runs into a problem similar to this I came up with a quick jQuery workaround which places an event on each form-group to detect clicks and then brings the child input into focus.

```
$("#application .form-group").on("click", function() {
  $(this).children('div').children('input').focus();
});
```